# SQL server suddently started to write huge amount of uknown data to tempdb

Tags: sql-server, performance, tempdb

so today our sql server suddently started to write a huge amount of data to the tempDB that resulting in disk spike so it can take up to 5 min before we can do anything in our program

tryed to take all our not so active databases offline and found out it was our production database that are doing it our developpers says that haven't been any updates for the program and is only us that are facing this issue

we had tryed to logout all the users one by one and it still writing alot of data to the tempdb

tryed to restart the server

and none of it had worked so far

so what can i do to actualy figuring out why it started to do this

[this is just when i am on our program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h99Cp.png)

server hpe proliant ml350p

HDD's running in raid 10

mssql 2014

Comment: I realize that I bust chops fairly often when people don't read the FAQ's here and post things that don't adhere to those FAQ's, so I have to ask; Is it the case that you think your statement of your problem is actually a question? It isn't. It's a statement. You've made a statement about your problem but you haven't actually asked a question. What you've written isn't of sufficient enough quality that people will take the time to give it any serious consideration much less take the time to answer.

Comment: How about providing details, like what version/edition of SQL Server, what version/edition of Windows, what applications are using SQL Server, hardware specs, etc., etc.

Comment: Use punctuations and start your sentences with capital letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run sp_who2 on the database to start to get an idea of what is happening.

http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/using-sp_who2

Once you find the process, you could kill it with: kill SPID#

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/kill-transact-sql

That may not be the smartest thing to do on a production database if you don't know how killing that process will affect your apps.